# jhipster aborts on windows due to .net sdk

Tags: .net, jhipster

Anyone installed and able to run the application successfully using jhipster on Windows?

I followed the steps as given on jhipster site. Once I faced problem as McAfee was running, turned it off, then it failed because Python was not installed, so I installed Python. Then it was failing due to the following error: .net sdk was not installed. Then I installed .net framework but still the error persists.

It would be nice if jiphister clarifies all these on jphister website, so that windows developers can actually feel the ease using jhipster. At the end I can see the application files in my folder and when I run `mvn spring-boot:run`, it even showing `BUILD SUCCESS`, but when I type `localhost:8080` in my browser I get the message unable to connect to server at localhost:8080. I have included the screen shot of my installed applications. How can I get rid of this .net sdk error while generating application using jhipster?

---

```
MSBUILD : error MSB3428: Could not load the Visual C++ component "VCBuild.exe".
 To fix this, 1) install the .NET Framework 2.0 SDK, 2) install Microsoft Visua
l Studio 2005 or 3) add the location of the component to the system path if it
is installed elsewhere.  [D:\savings\node_modules\grunt-browser-sync\node_modul
es\browser-sync\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modul
es\engine.io-client\node_modules\ws\node_modules\bufferutil\build\binding.sln]
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe
` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\
npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:269:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1074
:12)
 Windows_NT 6.3.9600
gyp ERR! command "node" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modu
les\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd D:\savings\node_modules\grunt-browser-sync\node_modules\browser-syn
c\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-cl
ient\node_modules\ws\node_modules\bufferutil
gyp ERR! node -v v0.12.7
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v2.0.1
gyp ERR! not ok
npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing utf-8-validate@1.1.0
```

---

The following is my full console log:

```
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v2.0.1
gyp ERR! not ok
npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing bufferutil@1.1.0


> utf-8-validate@1.1.0 install D:\savings\node_modules\grunt-browser-sync\node_m
odules\browser-sync\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_mo
dules\engine.io-client\node_modules\ws\node_modules\utf-8-validate
> node-gyp rebuild


D:\savings\node_modules\grunt-browser-sync\node_modules\browser-sync\node_module
s\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\node_mod
ules\ws\node_modules\utf-8-validate>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:
\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node
-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node  rebuild )
Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build,
please add the "/m" switch.
MSBUILD : error MSB3428: Could not load the Visual C++ component "VCBuild.exe".
 To fix this, 1) install the .NET Framework 2.0 SDK, 2) install Microsoft Visua
l Studio 2005 or 3) add the location of the component to the system path if it
is installed elsewhere.  [D:\savings\node_modules\grunt-browser-sync\node_modul
es\browser-sync\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modul
es\engine.io-client\node_modules\ws\node_modules\utf-8-validate\build\binding.s
ln]
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe
` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\
npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:269:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1074
:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.3.9600
gyp ERR! command "node" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modu
les\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd D:\savings\node_modules\grunt-browser-sync\node_modules\browser-syn
c\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-cl
ient\node_modules\ws\node_modules\utf-8-validate
gyp ERR! node -v v0.12.7
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v2.0.1
gyp ERR! not ok
npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing utf-8-validate@1.1.0


> bufferutil@1.1.0 install D:\savings\node_modules\grunt-browser-sync\node_modul
es\browser-sync\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_module
s\engine.io-client\node_modules\ws\node_modules\bufferutil
> node-gyp rebuild


D:\savings\node_modules\grunt-browser-sync\node_modules\browser-sync\node_module
s\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\node_mod
ules\ws\node_modules\bufferutil>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Pro
gram Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp
\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node  rebuild )
Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build,
please add the "/m" switch.
MSBUILD : error MSB3428: Could not load the Visual C++ component "VCBuild.exe".
 To fix this, 1) install the .NET Framework 2.0 SDK, 2) install Microsoft Visua
l Studio 2005 or 3) add the location of the component to the system path if it
is installed elsewhere.  [D:\savings\node_modules\grunt-browser-sync\node_modul
es\browser-sync\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modul
es\engine.io-client\node_modules\ws\node_modules\bufferutil\build\binding.sln]
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe
` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\
npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:269:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1074
:12)
 Windows_NT 6.3.9600
gyp ERR! command "node" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modu
les\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd D:\savings\node_modules\grunt-browser-sync\node_modules\browser-syn
c\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-cl
ient\node_modules\ws\node_modules\bufferutil
gyp ERR! node -v v0.12.7
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v2.0.1
gyp ERR! not ok
npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing utf-8-validate@1.1.0


> ws@0.4.32 install D:\savings\node_modules\karma\node_modules\socket.io\node_mo
dules\socket.io-client\node_modules\ws
> (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)

|
D:\savings\node_modules\karma\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-clie
nt\node_modules\ws>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Program Files\no
dejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp
.js" rebuild )  else (node  rebuild )
Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build,
please add the "/m" switch.
MSBUILD : error MSB3428: Could not load the Visual C++ component "VCBuild.exe".
 To fix this, 1) install the .NET Framework 2.0 SDK, 2) install Microsoft Visua
l Studio 2005 or 3) add the location of the component to the system path if it
is installed elsewhere.  [D:\savings\node_modules\karma\node_modules\socket.io\
node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\ws\build\binding.sln]
MSBUILD : error MSB3428: Could not load the Visual C++ component "VCBuild.exe".
 To fix this, 1) install the .NET Framework 2.0 SDK, 2) install Microsoft Visua
l Studio 2005 or 3) add the location of the component to the system path if it
is installed elsewhere.  [D:\savings\node_modules\karma\node_modules\socket.io\
node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\ws\build\binding.sln]
npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing bufferutil@1.1.0
/


> spawn-sync@1.0.13 postinstall D:\savings\node_modules\generator-jhipster\node_
modules\yeoman-generator\node_modules\cross-spawn\node_modules\spawn-sync
> node postinstall

npm WARN prefer global yo@1.4.7 should be installed with -g
-


> yo@1.4.7 postinstall D:\savings\node_modules\yo
> yodoctor

\
Yeoman Doctor
Running sanity checks on your system

√ Global configuration file is valid
√ NODE_PATH matches the npm root
√ Node.js version
√ No .bowerrc file in home directory
√ No .yo-rc.json file in home directory
√ npm version

Everything looks all right!
/
> yo@1.4.6 postinstall D:\savings\node_modules\generator-jhipster\node_modules\y
o
> yodoctor


Yeoman Doctor
Running sanity checks on your system

√ Global configuration file is valid
√ NODE_PATH matches the npm root
√ Node.js version
√ No .bowerrc file in home directory
√ No .yo-rc.json file in home directory
√ npm version

Everything looks all right!
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.3.9600
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs
\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
npm ERR! node v0.12.7
npm ERR! npm  v2.11.3
npm ERR! path C:\Users\madasuk\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\inherits\2.0.1\package\
package.json
npm ERR! code EPERM
npm ERR! errno -4048

npm ERR! Error: EPERM, rename 'C:\Users\madasuk\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\inheri
ts\2.0.1\package\package.json'
npm ERR!     at Error (native)
npm ERR!  { [Error: EPERM, rename 'C:\Users\madasuk\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\in
herits\2.0.1\package\package.json']
npm ERR!   errno: -4048,
npm ERR!   code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!   path: 'C:\\Users\\madasuk\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm-cache\\inherits\\2.0
.1\\package\\package.json',
npm ERR!   parent: 'readable-stream' }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     D:\savings\npm-debug.log
Running "ngconstant:dev" (ngconstant) task
Creating module savingApp at src/main/webapp/scripts/app/app.constants.js...OK

Running "wiredep:app" (wiredep) task
Warning: Error: Cannot find where you keep your Bower packages. Use --force to c
ontinue.

Aborted due to warnings.


Execution Time (2015-08-07 04:34:56 UTC)
loading tasks    78ms  ██████████████ 29%
ngconstant:dev   16ms  ███ 6%
wiredep:app     172ms  ██████████████████████████████ 65%
Total 266ms

bower cached        git://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr.git#2.8.3
bower validate      2.8.3 against git://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr.git#2.8.3

bower cached        git://github.com/jquery/jquery.git#2.1.4
bower validate      2.1.4 against git://github.com/jquery/jquery.git#2.1.4
bower cached        git://github.com/twbs/bootstrap.git#3.3.4
bower validate      3.3.4 against git://github.com/twbs/bootstrap.git#3.3.4
bower cached        git://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap-bower.git#0.13.1
bower validate      0.13.1 against git://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap-bower.g
it#0.13.1
bower cached        git://github.com/angular/bower-angular-resource.git#1.4.3
bower validate      1.4.3 against git://github.com/angular/bower-angular-resourc
e.git#1.4.3
bower cached        git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#1.4.3
bower validate      1.4.3 against git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#1.4
.3
bower cached        git://github.com/danialfarid/angular-file-upload-bower.git#5
.0.9
bower validate      5.0.9 against git://github.com/danialfarid/angular-file-uplo
ad-bower.git#5.0.9
bower cached        git://github.com/sroze/ngInfiniteScroll.git#1.2.0
bower validate      1.2.0 against git://github.com/sroze/ngInfiniteScroll.git#1.
2.0
bower cached        git://github.com/grevory/angular-local-storage.git#0.2.0
bower validate      0.2.0 against git://github.com/grevory/angular-local-storage
.git#0.2.0
bower cached        git://github.com/angular/bower-angular-scenario.git#1.4.3
bower validate      1.4.3 against git://github.com/angular/bower-angular-scenari
o.git#1.4.3
bower cached        git://github.com/saintmac/angular-cache-buster.git#0.4.3
bower validate      0.4.3 against git://github.com/saintmac/angular-cache-buster
.git#0.4.3
bower cached        git://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router.git#0.2.15
bower validate      0.2.15 against git://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router.git#0.2
.15
bower cached        git://github.com/bestiejs/json3.git#3.3.2
bower validate      3.3.2 against git://github.com/bestiejs/json3.git#3.3.2
bower cached        git://github.com/angular/bower-angular-sanitize.git#1.4.3
bower validate      1.4.3 against git://github.com/angular/bower-angular-sanitiz
e.git#1.4.3
bower cached        git://github.com/angular/bower-angular-cookies.git#1.4.3
bower validate      1.4.3 against git://github.com/angular/bower-angular-cookies
.git#1.4.3
bower cached        git://github.com/angular/bower-angular-mocks.git#1.4.3
bower validate      1.4.3 against git://github.com/angular/bower-angular-mocks.g
it#1.4.3
bower extra-resolution      Unnecessary resolution: angular#1.4.3
bower extra-resolution      Unnecessary resolution: angular-cookies#1.4.3
bower extra-resolution      Unnecessary resolution: jquery#2.1.4
bower install               angular-bootstrap#0.13.1
bower install               modernizr#2.8.3
bower install               jquery#2.1.4
bower install               ngInfiniteScroll#1.2.0
bower install               ng-file-upload#5.0.9
bower install               angular#1.4.3
bower install               angular-local-storage#0.2.0
bower install               angular-resource#1.4.3
bower install               angular-cache-buster#0.4.3
bower install               json3#3.3.2
bower install               angular-ui-router#0.2.15
bower install               bootstrap#3.3.4
bower install               angular-scenario#1.4.3
bower install               angular-sanitize#1.4.3
bower install               angular-cookies#1.4.3
bower install               angular-mocks#1.4.3

angular-bootstrap#0.13.1 src\main\webapp\bower_components\angular-bootstrap
└── angular#1.4.3

modernizr#2.8.3 src\main\webapp\bower_components\modernizr

jquery#2.1.4 src\main\webapp\bower_components\jquery

ngInfiniteScroll#1.2.0 src\main\webapp\bower_components\ngInfiniteScroll
└── angular#1.4.3

ng-file-upload#5.0.9 src\main\webapp\bower_components\ng-file-upload

angular#1.4.3 src\main\webapp\bower_components\angular

angular-local-storage#0.2.0 src\main\webapp\bower_components\angular-local-stora
ge

angular-resource#1.4.3 src\main\webapp\bower_components\angular-resource
└── angular#1.4.3

angular-cache-buster#0.4.3 src\main\webapp\bower_components\angular-cache-buster


json3#3.3.2 src\main\webapp\bower_components\json3

angular-ui-router#0.2.15 src\main\webapp\bower_components\angular-ui-router
└── angular#1.4.3

bootstrap#3.3.4 src\main\webapp\bower_components\bootstrap
└── jquery#2.1.4

angular-scenario#1.4.3 src\main\webapp\bower_components\angular-scenario
└── angular#1.4.3

angular-sanitize#1.4.3 src\main\webapp\bower_components\angular-sanitize
└── angular#1.4.3

angular-cookies#1.4.3 src\main\webapp\bower_components\angular-cookies
└── angular#1.4.3

angular-mocks#1.4.3 src\main\webapp\bower_components\angular-mocks
└── angular#1.4.3

D:\savings>
```

[image]

Comment: Looks like your node.js installation is faulty, it has nothing to do with jhipster.

Answer (score 0):

There are many Windows users using JHipster succesffully, as kryger commented the problem is in your node env.

Check your PATH, make sure your changes have been taking into account by restarting your command prompt or restarting your Windows session.

Test your env on a smaller installation than JHipster like only installin g browser-sync grunt task.

Comment: I am not sure whether it is with node env, because after I have installed Visual Studio, now I am not getting that error any more but coming across another problem that is related to Visual Studio, which I have posted as separate ticket on SO, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31874446/jhipster-isue-with-cl-exe-in-visual-studio-net. I am looking help from SO to clear off all these errors.

Comment: When I say node env it's general: meaning anything required by node/npm to work, it includes your OS settings (PATH and env variables), VS, Python and NodeJS. As you have discovered, Windows is not the easiest platform for NodeJS.