# issue with cl.exe in Visual Studio .Net

Tags: .net, visual-studio

When I am trying to use jhipster, I have got the following error:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Microsoft.CppBuild.targe
ts(366,5): warning MSB8003: Could not find WindowsSDKDir variable from the regi
stry.  TargetFrameworkVersion or PlatformToolset may be set to an invalid versi
on number. [D:\scost\node_modules\karma\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\soc
ket.io-client\node_modules\ws\build\validation.vcxproj]


 TRACKER : error TRK0005: Failed to locate: "CL.exe". The system cannot find the
     file specified. [D:\scost\node_modules\karma\node_modules\socket.io\node_modul
    es\socket.io-client\node_modules\ws\build\validation.vcxproj]
```

From https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/b60f4b90-8eb5-49fb-83c9-7259a3fae66e/need-help-with-trk0005-failed-to-locate-clexe, I realized it was due to multiple versions of visual studio installation. So I want to keep only the latest version of VS and delete all others. As I am new to .Net I am confused how to delete the older version of VS and keep only the latest VS. In Uninstall programs sections there so many .NET related entries, I don't know how to delete my 12.0 version and resolve this cl.exe issue. can any .NET expert help me please.

I have two folders in my system:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0
```

and

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0
```

Inside `12.0`, there is only one folder `Common7` but inside `14.0`, I have 19 folder like

```
Common7, Design Tools, Shell, VC, VC#, etc
```

And in `C \ Program Files` I have 12.0 folder as shown below it also has only `Common7` folder.

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0
```

Under `C \ Program Files`,  I don't have VS 14.0 folder at all.

I am using Windows 8.1.

Comment: You need only to delete visual studio itself, not all items with .net in it.

Comment: I also have multiple versions of visual studio. From what I understand the root cause is `node-gyp`. Setting the following environmental variable worked for me `set GYP_MSVS_VERSION=2013` (Change `2013` to whatever visual studio you have installed)